# Spiring @Cacheable is not working

Tags: spring, caching

I have added `<cache:annotation-driven />` in my Spring applicationcontext.xml.

Also added

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set><bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
name="executeCachedMethod" />
</set></property></bean>
```

Added  @Cacheable before a method that make a database call using JdbcTemplate.

Whenever I makes call to that method with same parameter method is always executed and goes to database. It supposed get me a cached result. Any help?

Comment: Add the Java code that you have annotated as `@Cacheable` with the actual class declaration.

Comment: Can you provide more context in java file ?

Comment: Actually was using in a spring bean during startup. By Spring implementation @cacheable only work after cacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated();  call is made. some where before we use cache  if we make this call cacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated();  it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was using it in a spring bean during startup. By Spring implementation `@cacheable` only work after `cacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated()` call is made. In my case I was using before that.

So just for testing

```
@Autowired
CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor;
```

Just to test the cache while load if we purposefully (not recommended)  make this call `cacheInterceptor.afterSingletonsInstantiated()`, cache will work.